# nthroot --> 7throot: Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been told that 'nthroot is a function that gives you the real n-th root of real numbers.' Replacing n with 7, I have experimented with variations of '7throot(49)' with no avail. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Always try `help nthroot` etc before asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the documentation for [nthroot](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/nthroot.html).

You need to use `nthroot(49,7)`.